# Book recommendations for relearning precalculus, for taking the GRE?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I am an international student. I am going to apply for a MA program in Economics but before doing that, I want to refresh all my math knowledge. I have to take the GRE so I need to re-learn precalculus. I really want to learn, not just do exercises fast. Axler's textbook is an incredible book on pre-calculus. To calculus, I have the simon-blume, but don't know if I ought use spivak's or apostol's  too. At university, I didn't use any book in calculus 1 or 2.

Comment: Your question is probably appropriate for the nearly-in-beta-SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education. 

Check out the proposal and commit to it if you're interested. Then we can get it off the ground and get the site in beta!

Answer (score 2):

Spivak's is excellent, with interesting problems and rigorous proofs. You will learn well from it.

Comment: But keep in mind that learning the rigorous proofs in Spivak is a lot of work that won't necessarily help with the GRE.  For GRE prep it may be more efficient to focus on the intuition.